# Making an Android application that cannot be uninstalled/deleted

Tags: java, android, security

I want to make a security app for Android phones. Basically, I don't want anyone to be able to un-install it without having to enter a specific password first.

Also, is there a way to prevent the app from being stopped manually (like being closed via. Taskmanager) etc?

Comment: `Mwhohahahahahaha`...the Title.

Answer (score 15):

This sounds more akin to Malware-like behaviour than that of a regular Android application, anyway:

For a regular Android application, I'd imagine that making it 'uninstallable' is near enough impossible to achieve - try to contemplate what the state of the Android app market would be like right now if this were possible!

On the other hand, if [privileged control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superuser) (root access) was available then this might be a possibility - an example of that could be like how wireless carriers implement [bundled software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-installed_software). **However**,  like I mentioned, there is no regular avenue available for applications released via. the Android market to achieve what you've asked, it should be pretty clear to you why...

Comment: I believe there are things he can do to achieve some of the things he asked though. A service will auto restart if passed the right flags on start, and by making the application a device administrator app it would ask for you to go there and disable it before you could uninstall.

Comment: @daniel imagine i dont want to put this application in market